# List of problems in the query complexity model with no super-polynomial quantum speedup

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, speedup

Similar to [this list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/np-hard-problems-on-trees) over at *cstheory*, I'm looking for a list of computational problems in the query complexity model for which it is known that no super-polynomial quantum speedups exist. What are some *natural* problems for which quantum computers are known to have only 'limited' advantage?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I am not sure if this is your are looking for, so I do not pretend this to be an answer.*

As far as I know, one example is calculation of a binary function parity. Binary function has odd parity in case it returns one for odd number of inputs. In other case it has even parity. In this task, a quantum computer is as fast as classical computer.

Comment: This is an excellent first entry for the list, thank you!